# One page check-out magento is suddenly failing?

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment-methods, failure

I had a working webshop, however, overnight the one page check out suddenly has multiple (probably related) problems.
It started with a failure on the customer's information, 'the password needs to match' - even with guest accounts where there is no password required. It solved this one by:

Find This line in Customer.php $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
Replace That that line with $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();

This worked, but now I have a failure at the payment method. It seems that it does not run a script. Did I have to change the line of code above in multiple directories? Does anyone else has this problem? I have tried almost everything it feels..

Thank you!

In addition:

I only know that it is a failure in the onepage checkout, because of this JS code:

//getActiveStep()): ?>
    accordion.openSection('opc-getActiveStep() ?>');
    
    var checkout = new Checkout(accordion,{
        progress: 'getUrl('checkout/onepage/progress') ?>',
        review: 'getUrl('checkout/onepage/review') ?>',
        saveMethod: 'getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveMethod') ?>',
        failure: 'getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'}
    );
//]]>

Comment: Do you have errors in the dev console ? Does js have errors ?

Comment: Check with the system logs or logs of the payment gateway if any.

Comment: If I check in the dev console, no errors; only this message which seems pretty standard and unrelated: Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform ; in the system.log also no errors found.. last message is from 2021 - which makes sense because I did not change anything since then.. SSL certificate is also up to date. 

Any other ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: See addition to the question, with the failure js and what it needs to do in that case (and what it is doing when choosing a payment method)